# Modelling Supply Induced Demand

Tags: consumer-theory, supply-and-demand

How would one go about modelling "supply induced demand" (SID) using the regular supply and demand model and how is SID different from price discrimination?

Comment: Well typically SID stems from asymmetric information, so you would have to do this within a Perfect Bayesian Nash Equilibrium context - so think principal agent type of problems. Price discrimination is just something a monopolist can sometimes do and that can occur in SID and non-SID contexts.